# executing .sh file - "./gradlew no such file or directory" and misc errors

Tags: windows, gradle, sh, gradlew

I'm trying to run a .sh file on `Windows`. More exactly I'm trying to run the build scripts in the following GitHub repo: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-for-unity.

But I'm extremely novice when it comes to .sh files. And came as far as executing the file by writing the following in "Git Shell": `sh ./setup.sh`.

I'm unsure which errors is actually "errors", but I've bolded what I think is the important issue. It's also worth mentioning that I've downloaded Gradle 3.1 and added it to my path variable. `gradle -v` does work (in cmd), but `gradlew` as a command does not. What am I missing? I feel stupid. :/

I get the following output/errors:

```
D:\GitHub\facebook-sdk-for-unity [tmp-test-bashscripts]> sh .\scripts\setup.sh
/d/GitHub/facebook-sdk-for-unity/scripts/local.properties: line 1: sdk.dir=D:\Android\android-sdk\sdk: No such file or directory
sed: can't read /FacebookSdkVersion.cs: No such file or directory
.\scripts\setup.sh: line 25: buildAndCopyCore: command not found
.\scripts\setup.sh: line 26: buildAndCopyPlatformDLLs: command not found
/d/GitHub/facebook-sdk-for-unity/scripts/local.properties: line 1: sdk.dir=D:\Android\android-sdk\sdk: No such file or directory
sed: can't read /FacebookSdkVersion.cs: No such file or directory
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 75.1M  100 75.1M    0     0   359k      0  0:03:33  0:03:33 --:--:--  372k
**/d/GitHub/facebook-sdk-for-unity/scripts/local.properties: line 1: sdk.dir=D:\Android\android-sdk\sdk: No such file or directory**
sed: can't read /FacebookSdkVersion.cs: No such file or directory
\033[0;36mStarting build \033[0m
\033[0;36mStep 1 - Cleaning wrapper libs folder \033[0m
/d/GitHub/facebook-sdk-for-unity/facebook-android-wrapper/libs /d/GitHub/facebook-sdk-for-unity
find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a non-option argument !, but options are not positional (-maxdepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments.

/d/GitHub/facebook-sdk-for-unity
\033[0;36mStep 2 - Get depenancies for android wrapper \033[0m
\033[0;36mStep 2.1.0 - Download bolts-android-1.4.0.jar \033[0m
\033[0;36mbolts-android-1.4.0.jar already exists. Skipping download. \033[0m
\033[0;36mStep 2.1.1 - Download bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar \033[0m
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   178  100   178    0     0    546      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   642
100   190  100   190    0     0    212      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   690
100 38092  100 38092    0     0  28892      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 28892
\033[0;36mStep 2.1.2 - Download bolts-applinks-1.4.0.jar \033[0m
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   178  100   178    0     0    650      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   661
100   196  100   196    0     0    233      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   233
100 25020  100 25020    0     0  20337      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  228k
\033[0;36mStep 2.2 - Download facebook-android-sdk-4.14.0.aar \033[0m
\033[0;36mfacebook-android-sdk-4.14.0.aar already exists. Skipping download \033[0m
\033[0;36mStep 2.3 - Coping support lib \033[0m
\033[0;36mStep 3 - Build android wrapper \033[0m
/d/GitHub/facebook-sdk-for-unity/facebook-android-wrapper /d/GitHub/facebook-sdk-for-unity
**/d/GitHub/facebook-sdk-for-unity/scripts/setup_android_unity_plugin.sh: line 118: ./gradlew: No such file or directory**

\033[0;31mFATAL: Failed to perform gradle clean \033[0m

\033[0;31mFATAL: Failed to build the android sdk plugin \033[0m
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running `sh .\scripts\setup.sh` in a `cmd` or Git CMD window. Open a Git Bash window instead. It's important to see "Bash" in its name. In that shell, go to the project directory with the `cd` command, and run `sh ./setup.sh` as it was written in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But that doesn't seem to be the issue. I downloaded Git with it's included Bash and tried running same scripts, but it threw the exact same log/errors. :(
Running the `sh` command in my "Git Shell" "works" (I get the errors as mentioned in OP).